# How to disable right click mouse move camera rotation in three.js when using OrbitControls?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using orbit controls for rotation of camera in three.j.

```
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

controls.dampingFactor = 0.07;
controls.rotateSpeed = 0.07;
controls.enableZoom = false;
controls.screenSpacePanning = false;
controls.minDistance = 250;
controls.maxDistance = 350;
controls.minPolarAngle = 1.2;
controls.maxPolarAngle = 1.2;
```

And I am fixing camera position like this -

```
camera.position.x = 308;
camera.position.y = 130;
camera.position.z = 135;
```

The camera moves around my object just fine when I use left click mouse move. But when I use right-click mouse move, it weirdly moves my camera away from the object. I need to disable this functionality but could not find any way to do that. I tried using event listeners on the document to block and stop propagation of mouse move event if followed by right click but it doesn't work.

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event){
  console.log(event.button);
  if(event.button == 2){
    rightmousemove = true;
    return false;
  //   // Right click
  } 
});
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
  if(rightmousemove === true){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're describing is 'panning'. You can disable this with:

`controls.enablePan = false;`

https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls.enablePan

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer what you want to do is disable panning which in this case can simply be achieved by using `controls.enablePan = false;`

Through I would also like to touch upon the topic of why your code was not working. This is because of event bubbling. In simple words it means that events(like `mousemove`) are triggered in the child element and move there way up to the parent element.

[image: Event bubbling]

So if the event(like click or mouse move) was triggered on the button element it will make its way up to the container div then to the document and then the window.

If you look at the source code of [OrbitControl.js](https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) . You will see that the mouse move is registered as `document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );`

So the end result is that both of you have registered it on the document object. The way `stopPropogation` work is that it will stop the event to bubble up to its parent object, but you have both registered it on the same object.

To achieve the desired result you can register it to a more specific element or use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`. The way `stopImmediatePropogation` works is it stops the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

[JS Fiddle code with stopImmediatePropogation](http://jsfiddle.net/shivasaxena/xt3cvy1e/19/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
controls = new OrbitControls(camera, container); // Reuse this if exist
controls.mouseButtons = {
    // LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.ROTATE,
    MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.DOLLY,
    // RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN
}
controls.update();// reuse this
```

as shown above, uncomment only the mouse controls that you want.

> ref: https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.mouseButtons